# What is the difference between sparse conditional constant propagation and constant propagation?

Tags: program-optimization

Reading the Wikipedia pages on these topics, it seems that sparse conditional constant propagation (SCCP) is a more powerful form of constant propagation (CP)? E.g all optimizations available in CP are subsumed in SCCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, SCCP will remove the unreachable blocks based on the previous const propagation, that's why it can propagate more constant (some phi's oprands can be removed)

And it's sparse, which means it runs on SSA form IR, that would make the analysis and procedure faster.

I read from a blog that there are four kinds of constant propagation, that is

- (simple) constant propagation
- conditional constant propagation
- sparse constant propagation
- sparse conditional constant propagation : the most powerful

Based on the attributes of each algorithm, I guess we can understand what they do.